# Limit git remotes completion

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using `git` `2.39.2` with `oh-my-zsh` through `antigen`.

Whenever I ask for completion, such as:

`git push ori<Tab>`

I have a bunch of unrelated results (eg. `origami.com`, `original.com`, `oriental.com`, etc.).

Is there a way to limit completion to remotes I have only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, zsh was picking domains in my `/etc/hosts` which was filled by [StevenBlack's hosts](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts/tree/master).

I have overridden some functions in my `~/.zshrc` to inhibit that:

```bash
__git_remote_repositories (){}
__git_local_repositories (){}
```